# How do I count the number of executions of an ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a number of hosts under a group in my inventory group that I want to execute a playbook for.  Is there a way for me to get the current count of executions within my task?  For example, I'm executing the playbook for my 2nd host.  I'd like there to be some variable available inside my task, say x=2 to reuse within my task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a facts "plugin". The [`setup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html) module optionally takes a `fact_path` parameter which by default points to `/etc/ansible/facts.d`. Any executable file within this folder will be executed when the setup module runs. So you could create a simple `sh` script which stores a counter in some file on your local box. The script then needs to return either JSON or INI format and the output will then be available in the server facts.

Comment: is that better than using a couple task's that creates a flat file to keep a number on (`0`), and reads and increments that number on each successive iteration? 

facts plugin or using fact_path sounds  heavier to setup.  Also may not want this to run for all plays so may need a way to have it execute only for one play, but thats secondary to the main point i raised above.